# 画像のファイルサイズと大きさを縮小しZIP圧縮するのですが、もう少しコードを短縮できないでしょうか？

Tags: c#

```
// 送られたパスの画像を圧縮する
private string ImageCoder(string path)
{
    int fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(path).Count();
    string[] fileTitles = Directory.GetFiles(path);
    Array.Sort(fileTitles, new LogicalStringComparer());

    string dirResize = path + @"\resize\";
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirResize);

    ImageCodecInfo jgpEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;
    EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

    for (int i = 0; i < fileCount; i++)
    {
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bmpSrc = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(fileTitles[i]);
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bmpSrcHalf = new System.Drawing.Bitmap
                (bmpSrc, RE_WIDTH, (int)(bmpSrc.Height * ((double)RE_WIDTH) / (double)(bmpSrc.Width)));

        EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter =
            new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, RE_COMP);

        myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
        bmpSrcHalf.Save(dirResize + (i + 1) + ".jpg", jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters);

        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(dirResize + (i + 1) + ".jpg");
        long reComp = RE_COMP;

        if (fileInfo.Length < 3000)
        {
            ShowBalloon("画像は削除されています。処理を中断します。");
            break;
        }

        while (fileInfo.Length > RE_SIZE)
        {
            myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, (reComp = reComp - 3));
            myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
            bmpSrcHalf.Save(dirResize + (i + 1) + ".jpg", jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
            fileInfo = new FileInfo(dirResize + (i + 1) + ".jpg");
        }
    }

    // ZIP化
    ZipStream(dirResize, path);

    return dirResize;
}
private ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
{
    ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();
    foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
        if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
            return codec;
    return null;
}


// 送られたパスのファイルをソートする
private string[] FileSort(string path)
{
    string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(path);
    fileNames = fileNames.OrderBy(n =>
    {
        int v = 0;
        if (int.TryParse(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(n), out v))
        {
            return v;
        }
        return 9999999; // 数字で無いファイル名は一番後ろになる様に
    }).ToArray();

    return fileNames;
}
```

Comment: 「画像は削除されています。」の判定条件がよくわかりませんでした。`fileTitles[i]`のファイルの存在を確認するのとは異なる意味を持つのでしょうか？

Comment: imgurのURLから画像をダウンロードした場合、１０ｋｂ程の小さい画像になって削除済みと書かれた画像がダウンロードされます。その際の処理です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LogicalStringComparer`、`GetEncoder`、`FileSort`の機能は取り込みました。
コメントに従い10KBで判定しました。
`GetImageDecoders()`でなく`GetImageEncoders()`を使いました。
きちんとリソース解放しました。
毎回ファイルに書き出さず、メモリ上で処理して最終結果だけをファイルに書き出しました。

```
// 送られたパスの画像を圧縮する
private string ImageCoder(string path) {
    var fileTitles = Directory.GetFiles(path).OrderBy(n => {
        int v = 0;
        return Int32.TryParse(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(n), out v) ? v : 9999999; // 数字で無いファイル名は一番後ろになる様に
    }).ToArray();

    var dirResize = Path.Combine(path, "resize");
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirResize);

    var jpegCodec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().FirstOrDefault(codec => codec.FormatID == ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid);

    for (int i = 0; i < fileTitles.Length; i++) {
        // １０ｋｂ程の小さい画像になって削除済みと書かれた画像がダウンロードされた場合
        if (new FileInfo(fileTitles[i]).Length < 10240) {
            ShowBalloon("画像は削除されています。処理を中断します。");
            break;
        }
        using (var original = new Bitmap(fileTitles[i]))
        using (var resized = new Bitmap(original, RE_WIDTH, (int)(original.Height * (double)RE_WIDTH / original.Width))) {
            var quality = RE_COMP;
            byte[] bytes;
            do {
                using (var memory = new MemoryStream()) {
                    resized.Save(memory, jpegCodec, new EncoderParameters { Param = new[] { new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, quality) } });
                    bytes = memory.ToArray();
                }
                quality -= 3;
            } while (bytes.Length > RE_SIZE);
            File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(dirResize, String.Format("{0}.jpg", i + 1)), bytes);
        }
    }

    // ZIP化
    ZipStream(dirResize, path);

    return dirResize;
}
```

Comment: 実装してみましたが、大変軽快で大満足しました。すっきりしてとても感謝しています。クラス化して永久保存版にしたいと思います！